# Specifying Where To Focus Within Textarea

Tags: javascript, focus

I have a textarea...

```
<textarea>
Some writing here
*
Then some more on another line
</textarea>
```

What I want to do is focus the user where the * is. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following function to set a selection within a textarea.

```
function setSelRange(inputEl, selStart, selEnd) { 
   if (inputEl.setSelectionRange) { 
     inputEl.focus(); 
     inputEl.setSelectionRange(selStart, selEnd); 
   } else if (inputEl.createTextRange) { 
     var range = inputEl.createTextRange(); 
     range.collapse(true); 
     range.moveEnd('character', selEnd); 
     range.moveStart('character', selStart); 
     range.select(); 
   } 
}
// From http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/4527.htm
```

So, in your case, you can search for the position of the `*` character and use that value in a call like this:

```
var pos = 17; // Set this to the position of the * character.
setSelRange(document.getElementById('textareaId'), pos, pos);
```

Comment: Needed some tweaking to suite what I wanted but it works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just to make your burden lighter.

```
<textarea id="myarea">
Some writing here
*
Then some more on another line
</textarea>


function FocusMe(what){ // what = character to be focused(in your case *)
 var cFocus = document.getElemenById("myarea").innerHTML;
 var pos = cFocus.indexOf(what);
 setSelRange(document.getElementById('myarea'), pos, pos); //Jame's answer above.
}
```