# Setting the focus on a specific row in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Set Cursor Position in Text Area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area)
>   [Specifying Where To Focus Within Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552567/specifying-where-to-focus-within-textarea)

I have a textarea with multiple lines. Let's say 10. How to set the cursor on the third line?

Comment: have you already seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-cursor-position-in-html-textbox

Comment: this is the answer:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499126/jquery-set-cursor-position-in-text-area